# jquery filtering not floating left with category selected

Tags: jquery, html, css, filter

I am brand new to learning about jQuery. I started with a youtube tutorial (which is a couple years old so I'm sure its a little out of date) and followed it to the tee but when I select one of my cateogry tabs the images disapear but the pictures that remain do not float to the left.

My question is what am I miss so the the category images float left when they are selected?

Here is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/staceylately/Lcu7h1rd/29/) for my code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.category_item').click(function(){
    var category = $(this).attr('id');

    if(category == 'all'){
        $('.icon').addClass('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.icon').removeClass('hide');
        }, 300);
    } else {
        $('.icon').addClass('hide');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('.' + category).removeClass('hide');
        }, 300);
    }
});

});
```

PS: It's working on my website but for some reason the filter isn't showing for me in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add display none to `.hide` in your css, it should be:

```
.hide {
  transform: scale(0);
  width:0;
  padding:0px;
  transition:all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  display: none; // THIS NEED TO UPDATE
}
```

It's work after add this `display: none`, check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Lcu7h1rd/31/